# Android Database Migration in Production

Tags: android, database, migration, objectbox, dbflow

I'm looking  (without success) a testing environment for my app database migration.

I'm working with ObjectBox and DBFlow in simultaneously and need to migrate my database in production, because some rows in entities and entities, was edited, created or deleted.

How I can test it in my local environment to get sure that everything works in Play Store.

There is some framework, tool, or anything to test it the migration before release it?

Thanks

Expecting: Success in Android release database migration.